# How are the motors coupled to pulleys in this scara robot?

Tags: motors, robotics, pulleys

Several years ago the CoRETS group posted a animated video about a novel SCARA robot https://youtu.be/P3iIIqFkSIc but there are no references to it in the literature.  I cannot understand how the two motors shown are able to actuate the pulleys below given their location. The only thing I can think of is some kind of way to run one motor shaft through the other motor shaft. I am assume from the animation that there are two motors located above the arms and pulleys.

In the video screenshot below you can see that someone asked this very question but it remains unanswered.

[image]

Comment: Yes it looks like coaxial motors.

Comment: look at an analog mechanical clock